# Guessing Game Bug?

Tags: python

I have the following code written in Python as a project. I have taken Computer Science as a GCSE. I am quite new to it, so do not know how to fix this bug. When I type in my first guess, e.g '5', it will say Too High. Then once the game is complete, it will say the answer is 7. It is a bug that I have constantly tried to solve but could not accomplish. Here is the code I have used:

```
import random 
numberofGuesses = 0 
print ("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10. What is it? You have three guesses.") 

while numberofGuesses < 3: 
    numberofGuesses = numberofGuesses +1 
    randomNumber = (random.randint(1,10)) 
    userInput = 0
    userInput = input () 
    userInput = int(userInput) 
    if randomNumber > userInput: 
        print("Too Low! Try again")
    if randomNumber < userInput:
        print("Too High! Try Again")

if numberofGuesses == 3:
    print("Sorry! You lose. The correct number was:",randomNumber)

if randomNumber == userInput: 
    print("Well Done! Your guess was correct!")`
```

This code works perfectly apart from the one bug I mentioned.

Comment: The answer below is correct. Just one nitpick, the line `userInput = 0` is not necessary.

Comment: You should also look at exiting the loop when they have guessed correctly, other it will make them guess again.

Answer (score 7):

You are reselecting a random number each time you make a guess.  Instead I believe you would like to have the program pick a number first, then enter your while loop.

```
randomNumber = (random.randint(1,10)) 

while numberofGuesses < 3: 

    numberofGuesses = numberofGuesses +1 

    userInput = 0

    userInput = input () 

    userInput = int(userInput) 

    if randomNumber > userInput: 

        print("Too Low! Try again")

    if randomNumber < userInput:

        print("Too High! Try Again")
```

Answer (score 3):

There's another problem besides the resetting of the random number in every iteration:

You're not stopping the loop if the guess was correct. And you should increase the guess counter *after* the evaluation of the guess, or else you won't be able to tell if someone guessed correctly on the third try:

```
import random 
numberofGuesses = 0 
randomNumber = (random.randint(1,10)) 
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10. What is it? You have three guesses.") 

while numberofGuesses < 3: 
    userInput = int(input()) 
    if randomNumber > userInput: 
        print("Too Low! Try again")
    elif randomNumber < userInput:
        print("Too High! Try Again")
    else: # Correct guess!
        break
    numberofGuesses = numberofGuesses +1 
else:  # Executed only if the while loop is not exited via "break"
    print("Sorry! You lose. The correct number was:",randomNumber)

if randomNumber == userInput: 
    print("Well Done! Your guess was correct!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the randomNumber to a new random number with each guess - So for the first answer, it might be 7, and then you make a guess and it changes to 3. To fix this, move `randomNumber = (random.randint(1,10))` outside of your while loop - Do it once, not once per guess. Cheers and good luck in your learning!